# Windows 7 x64 can't connect to a printer on a 32-bit server

Tags: windows-7, printing, windows-server-2003

I have a Windows 7 64-bit PC which is trying to print on a printer which is hosted by a Windows 2003 server. The server is a 32-bit OS. I cant locate any drivers for the printer. I've tried numerous things on the server like re install the latest drivers. I even tried to connect the Windows 7 x64 machine to the printer locally and it still doesn't work. The 32-bit version of Windows 7 works perfectly. anybody have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the Win7x64 printer drivers on the server.  (I know, I know, sounds crazy.  But I have come across this on my work network)

After the x64 driver is installed, deploy the printer with the Print Management console from the server.  It will push the printer to the clients with the proper driver.

Any future driver updates will be made on the server after that, which will push to the client.

Good Luck

Comment: thank you. i have already tried that but the windows 2003 server would not take a 64 bit windows 7 driver. I have tried using the windows 7 32-bit driver since 64-bit OS should work with 32-bit software, but still no luck. I am trying to install printers locally but for some reason i can't get anything to print on the printer. Even though it is connected.

Comment: How are you adding the driver?  It will not get installed with an .exe.  It needs to be added by using the Print Management mmc.  The printer does need to be installed to the server with it's own (32bit) driver.  You're not installing the printer to the server with the Win7 driver...You are adding the driver to the server so it can install it to the Win7 clients.  Let me know if you need further detailed steps.

Comment: So i go to the server management screen. I click on "add printer driver" under the print server section. then the driver installation screen pops up. when i get to the section to select operating systems that will use the driver. They only have up until windows XP x64 or x86. i check the x64 box anyways and locate the driver file ( i know its not an exe.) and i get an error saying i cant install this

Comment: I found this article on TechNet that may help.  While similar to what you did, slightly different. http://blogs.technet.com/b/yongrhee/archive/2009/09/14/how-to-add-64-bit-print-drivers-on-32-bit-windows-server-2003-or-windows-server-2008-print-server.aspx  I was also thinking you might be able to get around that doing everything from the Win7 machine with Remote Admin Tools.  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7887  Run the Print Management mmc from your PC connected to the server remotely.  FYI: It's a big download.

Answer (score 0):

1. First, you need to know the name of the computer which hosts the printer, and the name of the printer to be shared.
   Sitting at the host computer: Start > Computer > Properties > Computer Name tab > Change button. Write down the name that you see here because this is the computer name.
   Start > Printers and Faxes > Right click on the printer to be shared > Properties > Sharing tab. Write down the name that you see here because this is the printer name.
2. Now from the Windows 7 64bit computer
   Start > Devices and Printers > Add printer > Add a local printer > Click on ‘Create a new port’ > ‘Local Port’ > ‘Next’.
   The port name will look like this: \Computer name\printer name
   So enter the names already retrieved, ensuring that you use the same format, then click ‘OK’.
3. Add the Driver
   At this point, you will be presented with the ‘Add New Hardware’ process. Continue setup the same as you normally would installing the 64 bit driver. The printer will be added, and you should be able to print a test page.